# How to use for-loop in an macro of excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am completely new to Excel, but I want to make a macro where I can fill in two columns, and the start and end number of the rows, and it will do like this:

```
=(A1*B1+A2*B2+A3*B3...)/((SUM of column B)/N))
```

where `N` is the number of rows.

How would I make this in excel?

Comment: This is a little confusing. Is C11*C21, for instance, saying "Column 11 multiplied by Column 21", or is that reference to Cell C11 and C21. Same question for "SUM OF C2".

Comment: I meant column 1 row 1 multiplied by column 2 row 1! Sum of C2 is the sum of all numbers in column 2! I understand that this was confusing :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, things will be a lot easier if you use the standard cell addresses!

Generally cells are referred to by their "A1" -addresses, but in *VBA* (Visual Basic for Applications) they can also be referred to by using [Row, Column] coordinates. For example `Cell(1, 2)` would be "B1".

---

You can calculate the value with either *Formulas* or with custom *VBA* (macros).
Formulas are often the easier alternative - but there are definitely merits in using *VBA* in some cases.

### Using Formulas

Here's the layout of the sample data:

[image: Sample data layout.]

Column *A* and *B* are both filled with the numbers to be multiplied together.

Cell "C2" contains the formula used to calculate the value.

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(A:A;B:B)/SUM(B:B))/(COUNTA(B:B)-1)
```

- `SUMPRODUCT` multiplies the values of columns *A* and *B* for each row and sums them up.
- `SUM` adds up all the numbers found in column *B*.
- `COUNTA` calculates the number of non-empty cells in column *B* (we have to deduct the header).

Look up the functions on the Microsoft Office [support page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-functions-alphabetical-list-HA010277524.aspx) for more information.

### Using VBA

You can achieve the same thing (and much more!) using *VBA*.

Open up the *VBE* (Visual Basic Editor) with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> or from the [Developer Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx).

Create a new Standard Code Module.

[image]

Paste the code below into the module. You can tweak it to better suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim valueColumnA As Long
    Dim valueColumnB As Long
    Dim headerSize As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim value As Double

    '''---Config---'''
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    valueColumnA = 1
    valueColumnB = 2
    headerSize = 1
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '''---Logic---'''
    'Multiply the columns for each row and sum them up
    For currentRow = headerSize + 1 To lastRow
        value = value _
            + targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, valueColumnA).value _
            * targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, valueColumnB).value
    Next

    'Divide by sum of numbers found in valueColumnB
    value = value / Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
        targetSheet.Columns(valueColumnB))

    'Divide by number of rows
    value = value / (lastRow - headerSize)

    Debug.Print value
End Sub
```

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) has a lot of good questions and answers about *VBA*.